# LNK2005 error with Zxing C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, zxing

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Zxing c++ core to build a Windows Runtime Component.
I included my c++ files in my project.

When I compile, I got the following error:

```
Error   32  error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned int const
zxing::DecodeHints::CHARACTER_SET" (?CHARACTER_SET@DecodeHints@zxing@@2IB) 
already defined in MyObject.obj
```

I found a thread on Google (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/U5dLnFjsDwQ) but this didn't solve my problem.

Any idea ?

Comment: It is suggesting zxing::DecodeHints::CHARACTER_SET is defined twice. Is it defined in a header file?

Comment: Well, I just have a header file called DecodeHints.h where I have:
#ifndef __DECODEHINTS_H_
#define __DECODEHINTS_H_

Comment: What is weird is that in DecodeHint.h, I have "static const DecodeHintType CHARACTER_SET = 1 << 30;" AND in DecodeHint.cpp, I also have "const DecodeHintType DecodeHints::CHARACTER_SET";

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been solved (for now). The CHARACTER_SET was instantiated in the .h file and not in the cpp. For a reason that I do not know, the Visual compiler does not allow that, while there was no problem with GCC.

**Old code:**

DecodeHints.h:

```
static const DecodeHintType CHARACTER_SET = 1 << 30;
```

DecodeHints.cpp:

```
const DecodeHintType DecodeHints::CHARACTER_SET;
```

**has been replaced by:**

DecodeHints.h:

```
static const DecodeHintType CHARACTER_SET;
```

DecodeHints.cpp:

```
const DecodeHintType DecodeHints::CHARACTER_SET = 1 << 30;
```